# Mercurial - When to use update

Tags: mercurial, merge

When do I use update vs merge?  If I do a pull from a remote repository, I'm reading that I have to do update to get those changes into my working directory.  But others times I'm reading that I have to do merge.

Do I maybe want to always do an update after a pull, and then do a merge only if there are conflicts?

What am I not understanding here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you have local commits: merge.  If you have uncommitted local modifications: update (which will merge).

Usually when you make a commit locally, it forks the tree when you pull.  In this case you always have to merge (or rebase with the rebase extension).  If you have uncommitted local modifications, then when you pull, you can update and merge the changes into your workspace.

Comment: While this is correct in the technical sense, understand that pulling and updating into an uncommitted (dirty) working directory is losing a lot of the benefit of mercurial. If you have meaningful changes, commit them first so as to not corrupt the context and potentially lose work in the merge.

Answer (score 16):

- [`hg update`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Update) is about making your working directory the same than a given revision
- hg merge won't reset your working directory to a given revision (it still refers the same), but will merge changes from another revision into your current working directory.

So after a pull, an hg update will *change* your working directory to reflect what you have pulled into your repository.
But hg merge will not reset your working directory, only merge the changes between your working directory and what you have pulled.

`hg pull -u` will pull and update, refusing to merge or overwrite local changes.

- If the pull add a new HEAD in your repo, you will need to merge

```
added 1 changesets with 1 changes to 1 files (+1 heads)
(run 'hg heads' to see heads, 'hg merge' to merge)
```

- If the pull add no new HEAD in your repo, a simple update is enough